# How to download all pages in URL formed as http://example.com/resource?p=NN

Tags: shell, wget

I have looked through wget manpage but could not find a native way of using it.
The only solution that comes to my mind is to wrap a wget line into a shell script and then redirect all resulting single files into a final one.

Can you suggest a simpler, faster, more elegant approach?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Wait, what is it exactly that you're trying to do? Why is `wget -r example.com/resource?p=NN` not enough?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: If I wrap the wget in a shell script and have NN handled by it yes it works but it's quite a kludge. I end up with a bunch of files, have to catenate them etc. So yes I do have an horrible but working solution. The question was if any of you can come up with something simpler cleverer ... Thank you